# $(window).scroll not firing

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I am using Sharepoint developper. Inside the page I have custom JQuery code which works fine. But when I add the $(window).scroll it does not fire.

```
function TTNListScroll()
{
var bestaatDiv = document.getElementById("header-fixed");
if(bestaatDiv ==null){
    alert("mag maar 1 keer komen");
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("thead");
    TTNmyTable = head[0].parentNode;
    TTNmyTable.id="table-1";
    var parent = TTNmyTable.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(TTNmyTable);
    parent.appendChild(TTNmyTable);
    var newTable=document.createElement("table");
    newTable.id="header-fixed";
    parent.appendChild(newTable);

    var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
    var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
    var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
    alert('a');
    });
    alert($._data(window).events.scroll);
    alert($(window).height());
    }
}
```

The function is defined inside the document.ready 
My goal is to freeze a table header when i scroll down.

If anybody has any ideas they are well appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does `TTNListScroll` get called?  You define the function, but it appears you dont call it so the event wont get binded.

Alternatively, try to bind the scroll event to the `'html, body'` instead of `window`, like so:

```
$('html, body').scroll(function() { ... });
```

And last but not least, you could try to bind the different scroll events directly. jQuery should take care of this, but maybe it does not correctly:

```
$('html, body').bind('DOMMouseScroll MouseScrollEvent MozMousePixelScroll wheel scroll', function() { your code });
```

Comment: Hi, I tried but it failed. I'm guessing that the javascript from the sharepoint designer is blocking the scroll event. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: are you putting your jquery code in a document ready wrapper?

Comment: Your super!! finally it helped me

Comment: $('html, body').scroll(function() worked for me, Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, and the cause was there is a conflict with this css, once I removed the overflow in this css, it worked.

```
html,body {
 height:100%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Very obscure, but this actually fixed my issue.

Comment: Also check out for 
`overflow: auto`